# How to build application to put executable on the desktop

Tags: xcode

I created an app and it runs on "My Mac 64-bit".
Now I want to put the executable on my Mac desktop.  Where is it and how can I do this?
Oh and can I put the executable on a flash drive and put on somebody else's Mac?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are building in Xcode.

Open your project, from the Product menu, select "Archive." Then open the organizer, go to Archives, select your program, and click "Share."

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

You can contextually (right- or control-) click the build product in the Navigation view and select the "Show in Finder" menu item to open the folder (in the Finder) where it was built. Note that Debug builds will usually only run where they're built… but release builds can be moved or copied anywhere…